# Inverse of $x$ in a field under ordinary multiplication but redefined addition.

Tags: abstract-algebra

On $\mathbb R$, let us define $$\phi((a,b))= a+b-2$$ and $$\psi((a,b))= \text{ ordinary multiplication on }\mathbb R$$

I have checked that $(\mathbb R, \phi, \psi)$ forms a field. Let us say $e_{\phi}$ is the identity under $\phi$, $e_{\psi}$ is the identity under $\psi$, $(-a)$ is the inverse under $\phi$, and $a^{-1}$ is the inverse under $\psi$. So, in this field: 
$$e_{\phi} = 2$$$$e_{\psi}=1$$$$(-a)=4-a$$$$a^{-1}=\frac1a$$

In my professor's field axioms, the axiom for multiplicative inverse states (set adjusted to reflect my set in this post):

For each $x \in \mathbb R \space s.t. x \neq0, \exists x^{-1} \in \mathbb R \space s.t. \psi((x^{-1},x))=1$

Now my question is: Since $x \neq 0$ which in this case is $x \neq 2$, does $x = 0$ have an inverse? (Where $0$ is the numeral $0$ in $\mathbb R$).  I am not sure since the numeral $0$ times anything is the numeral $0$, but in this case should equal $1$, and also since $0^{-1}=\frac10$ and $\frac10$ does not exist. But under the axioms, $0$ should have an inverse since $x$ can be anything except $2$.

Comment: This indicates that you don't have a field with these operations.

Comment: I don't understand.  All field axioms are satisfied. Please explain

Comment: $a(b\vec{+}c)=a(b+c-2)=ab+ac-2a$ but $ab\vec{+}ac=ab+ac-2$

Comment: Ok, I see now. THANK YOU VERY MUCH! I'M relieved. However, generally speaking, does $0$ have an inverse in a field on $\mathbb R$?

Comment: Since $\frac10$ does not exist in $\mathbb R$

Comment: Not if the multiplication is the usual one (as you have shown).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your axioms. In particular;

Multiplication distributes over addition:

$$ a ⋅ (b + c) = (a ⋅ b) + (a ⋅ c)$$  and
$$(b + c) ⋅ a = (b ⋅ a) + (c ⋅ a)$$ 
Which will fail for your binary operations on $\mathbb{R}$. So it's not even a ring and therefor not a field. (But perhaps a nice example of a "near-ring" where the distributive property fails?)

$$a(b+⃗ c)=a(b+c−2)=ab+ac−2a, \text{where }b+⃗ c = \phi(b,c) $$
$$\neq $$
$$ab+⃗ ac=ab+ac−2 $$
(stolen from user84413)
These are not equal since $-2a \neq -2$.

Comment: These two equations should be equal since multiplication commutes

Comment: Did you try to calculate it? It will fail.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.  What does the arrow over the addition symbol mean?

Comment: @JohannFranklin Its your addition $\phi$ :)

Answer (score 1):

Go back and check to make *sure* you're not mistaken in saying it's a field (and look very closely at examples involving $1/2$ when you're trying to show the distribution property).

Comment: $a*(b+c)=ab+ac=ab+ac-2$.  Am I missing something?

Comment: $1/2*\phi(a,b)=1/2*(a+b-2)=\frac{a+b}{2}-1$ which isn't the same as $\phi(a/2,b/2)=\frac{a+b}{2}-2$.

Comment: But you are carrying out the 1st operation, then distributing. Is this allowed? I was under the assumption that one must distribute first, then carry out operations.